# How can I move the subdomain to the root domain?

Tags: subdomains, domain

So my blogs and faq pages and forums are under a subdomain (like example.yolo.com/faq, example.yolo.com/blog, example.yolo.com/forum)

What I want to do is remove the "example" sub domain and just have yolo.com/blog and so on.

I followed this guide where they asked me to copy the contents of the blog folder and put the contents directly under the public.html folder. But if I do that for all 3 directories, I guess it'll overwrite the files. (Guide link: https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/how-to-move-a-wordpress-subdomain-to-the-root-domain/ )

So how can I get it done?

Comment: You shouldn't have to move the files if you can just change your Apache configuration. How are you hosting this - do you have control over the Apache config? You should just be able to change the VirtualDomain lines with the new host names and leave the files where they are. You'll need to do all the in-WordPress config steps though.

Comment: But when you say "for all 3 directories" are these three separate WordPress instances? If it's just changing the domain name then that should all be fine, but if you trying to combine them into one site or a network then that's more work too.

Comment: kindly provide your exact scenario..
- Can you confirm, is your blog running with Wordpress ?
- If is wwordpress, what are those 3 directories ? Normally WP has few directories with more sub directories itself.
- your main wordpress is using ('example.yolo.com') or ('yolo.com')